# How to Match Tilde-Delimited Data Using Regex

Tags: regex, notepad++, tilde

I have data like this:

```
~10~682423~15~Test Data~10~68276127~15~More Data~10~6813~15~Also Data~
```

I'm trying to use Notepad++ to find and replace the values within tag 10 (682423, 68276127, 6813) with zeroes. I thought the syntax below would work, but it selects the first occurrence of the text I want **and the rest of the line**, instead of just the text I want (`~10~682423~`, for example). I also tried dozens of variations from searching online, but they also either did the same thing or wouldn't return any results.

```
~10~.*~
```

Comment: I want to replace the values within tag 10 (682423, 68276127, 6813) with zeroes. Added to original description too. Thanks.

Comment: [It works](https://regex101.com/r/mMEAT2/1) for me

Comment: Thanks @Asocia, yes this works. And very simple. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\b10~\d+
```

Replace with `10~0`. See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Uv2NEL/2). `\b10~` will capture `10` as entire number (no match in `210` is allowed) and `\d+` will match one or more digits.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I remove capture group, I took your advice.

Comment: What was life before Stack Overflow? This worked almost perfectly for me. The only change was to include another tilde at the beginning to ensure I only pick up tag `10`. Without the leading tilde, any fields that end with the number 10 will get picked up. This was the end result: `~\b10~\d+`. Thanks!

Comment: @Jawann `~\b10~\d+` is the same as `~10~\d+` since `~` is not a word char.

Answer (score 2):

You can use: `(?<=~10~)\d+(?=~)` and replace with `0`.  This uses lookarounds to check that `~10~` precedes the digit sequence and the `(?=~)` ensures a `~` follows the digit sequence. If any character could be after the `~10~` field, use `(?<=~10~)[^~]+(?=~)`.

The problem with `~10~.*~` is that the `*` is greedy, so it just slurps away matching any character and `~`.

Comment: This works perfectly, and even more elegantly than I expected. Your explanation about why my strategy didn't work is very helpful. Goes to show I have a lot to learn about regex. I selected the other answer because that's the one I used, but this one will help improve my skills more in the long-run. Thanks!